# How do I find a phone number in the body of an email using Windows Search?

Tags: windows, windows-search

I am pretty sure that I have an email with somebody's phone number in it, I'll call him Bob. But all I know is the person's name. I have lots of email that includes their name so I'd like to use Outlook or Windows 7 search to find "Bob and (???) ???-????" where ? is a wildcard for any digit. I've tried that exact search and it doesn't work. Does Windows 7 search support anything like this and if so what is the syntax?

Comment: Most of the links I've found on the Internet are broken but look like they were to a Windows XP support site.

Comment: Use wildcard to search the contents like `*Bob` will search all the file which contain the Bob text

Comment: Yeah but i have hundreds of those. I want the ones that also contain a phone number.

Comment: Then I think you can also search by follow the phone number. However I never tried it because for me Windows search sucks. I use [agentransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) which is very good tool for me.

Comment: Do you know any part of the phone number, like area code?  That would at least narrow the search.  As far as the broken links, you can use the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/index.php) to [see them](http://web.archive.org/web/20110416053831/http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/choose/tipsandtricks.mspx).

Comment: I had some guesses and used those to try to narrow it down but had no luck. I ended up emailing the guy again to get his number but now I am curious if there is a way to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Windows Search Advanced Page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Advanced-tips-for-searching-in-Windows):

```
You can use a question mark (?) as a wildcard for a single character and
an asterisk (*) as a wildcard for any number of characters.
```

So your suggestion should find the email

Comment: I should have made it more clear in my question. That search doesn't work.

Comment: @GregB have you tried with the tool I suggested you.

Comment: This is on my work issued laptop so I am not able to add programs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure:

1. Open `Windows Explorer` or `Computer`
2. Click on `Organize`, it will open up a drop-down menu
3. Select `Folder and Search` option, and select `Search` tab it will open up a dialog as:

   [image]
4. Now Put a *check* on "Always search file names and contents"
5. Open `Search` window by the shortcut provided on most of the keyboard while focus on *Desktop*, if you don't have shortcut, then, Open `Windows Explorer`, in the Address bar type `search-ms:` and press `Enter` key.
6. Type the number you want to search in the provided side search box
7. Select the `Kind` type as `Email` (When you click on `Kind:` it will open up the list in which choose email)

**So, here you go!** Now windows is going to search every email on file system for your number itself in the contents..
Moreover

> You can use a question mark (?) as a wildcard for a single character and an asterisk (*) as a wildcard for any number of characters...[courtesy](https://superuser.com/a/439405/139215)

Cheers..

Comment: I looked at this and I already had all of these boxes checked. When I put ???-???? in the search results none of results that are returned are emails. If I do '???-???? kind:email' then I get no results. But I know that I have emails that contain 555-5555.